# Error when connecting CloudSQL MySQL public IP from C# CloudRun

Tags: c#, mysql, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

Hi I am trying to connect my CloudRun to CloudSQL MySQL using public IP.
I can connect successfully with public ip but I needed to allow all networks 0.0.0.0 for CloudSQL.

I am now trying to connect this way:

```
    public DapperContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        // Equivalent connection string:
        // "Server=<dbSocketDir>/<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>;Uid=<DB_USER>;Pwd=<DB_PASS>;Database=<DB_NAME>;Protocol=unix"
        //String dbSocketDir = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_SOCKET_PATH") ;
        //String instanceConnectionName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME");

        var connectionString = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            // The Cloud SQL proxy provides encryption between the proxy and instance.
            SslMode = MySqlSslMode.None,

            // Remember - storing secrets in plain text is potentially unsafe. Consider using
            // something like https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/overview to help keep
            // secrets secret.
            Server = "/cloudsql/master-xxxxx-12341234:asia-southeast2:mysql-1",
            //Server = $"{dbSocketDir}/{instanceConnectionName}",
            UserID = "root",   // e.g. 'my-db-user
            Password = "123456", // e.g. 'my-db-password'
            Database = "db-name", // e.g. 'my-database'
            ConnectionProtocol = MySqlConnectionProtocol.UnixSocket,
            Pooling = true
        };
        // Specify additional properties here.
        _connectionString = connectionString.ConnectionString;
    }

    public IDbConnection CreateConnection() => new MySqlConnection(_connectionString);
```

However I am getting "Unknown socket error" and from CloudSQL logs: "[MY-010914] [Server] Got an error reading communication packets"

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, your Google cloud should not have a public IP (in your scenario) since they can talk to each other privately.
Now with regards to your request there are some options:

1-Within the Sql screen check Public IP and on the New network, provide a name and most important a value of 0.0.0.0/0 **Notice the warning**

[image]

2-Connect using the Cloud SQL Auth proxy

Using the Cloud SQL Auth proxy is the recommended method for connecting to a Cloud SQL instance. The Cloud SQL Auth proxy:

- Works with both public and private IP endpoints
- Validates connections using credentials for a user or service account
- Wraps the connection in a SSL/TLS layer that's authorized for a Cloud SQL instance

That said going directly to a response.

**Notice:** Be sure to Enable Cloud Sql Admin api, more info [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy?authuser=3)

1-Check your cloud run configuration, on the command line make the following replacements.

- IMAGE with the image you are deploying
- SERVICE_NAME with the name of your Cloud Run service
- INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME with the instance connection
  name of your Cloud SQL instance, or a comma delimited
  list of connection names.

  gcloud run deploy 
  --image=IMAGE 
  --add-cloudsql-instances=INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME

2-Connect to CloudSQL

For public IP paths, Cloud Run provides encryption and connects using the **Cloud SQL Auth proxy** through Unix sockets.

Once correctly configured, you can connect your service to your Cloud SQL instance's Unix domain socket accessed on the environment's filesystem at the following path: /cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME.

The INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME uses the format project:region:instance-id. You can find it on the Overview page for your instance in the Google Cloud console or by running the following command:

gcloud sql instances describe [INSTANCE_NAME]

The code sample shown below is an extract from more complex examples located [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/cloud-sql/mysql/ConnectUnix.cs)

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;

namespace CloudSql
{
    public class MySqlUnix
    {
        public static MySqlConnectionStringBuilder NewMysqlUnixSocketConnectionString()
        {
            // Equivalent connection string:
            // "Server=<INSTANCE_UNIX_SOCKET>;Uid=<DB_USER>;Pwd=<DB_PASS>;Database=<DB_NAME>;Protocol=unix"
            var connectionString = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder()
            {
                // The Cloud SQL proxy provides encryption between the proxy and instance.
                SslMode = MySqlSslMode.None,

                // Note: Saving credentials in environment variables is convenient, but not
                // secure - consider a more secure solution such as
                // Cloud Secret Manager (https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager) to help
                // keep secrets safe.
                Server = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("INSTANCE_UNIX_SOCKET"), // e.g. '/cloudsql/project:region:instance'
                UserID = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_USER"),   // e.g. 'my-db-user
                Password = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_PASS"), // e.g. 'my-db-password'
                Database = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_NAME"), // e.g. 'my-database'
                ConnectionProtocol = MySqlConnectionProtocol.UnixSocket
            };
            connectionString.Pooling = true;
            // Specify additional properties here.
            return connectionString;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the sample code but I still got the same error.

Comment: try setting the IP on the Server variable and double check if you enabled the api, If still persists do you mind to provide further errors details ? Thanks

Comment: Hi @jmvcollaborator I am trying to connect using the Unix socket. I am using Cloud run which is calling Cloud Build to publish my net6 app.  I have added cloud-sql-client role to default_compute_engine and cloudbuild service agents. I have added CloudSQL connection to CloudRun settings->connections. I also added   '--add-cloudsql-instances', 'xxxxx-xxxxx-123123:asia-southeast2:mysql-instance', to my cloudbuild.yaml deploy command. The only errors, I can see is "Unknown socket error" and "[MY-010914] [Server] Got an error reading communication packets" from CloudSQL logs

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days of searching the problem was the version of MySQL.Data, the version that worked for me is 8.0.23, for more info https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=104685